# This new puzzle type needs a name {7}

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, grid-deduction, nonogram, reverse-puzzling

<sub>*This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #5: On-and-onograms](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/monthly-topic-challenge-5-on-and-onograms) - and also extends the '[This new puzzle type needs a name](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20%22new%20puzzle%20type%20needs%20a%20name%22%20is%3aquestion%20%5bgrid-deduction%5d)' series...*</sub>

---

I believe I have invented a new type of puzzle...

> **What is its name?**

[image: Nonogram to be solved]

Begin by solving the 32x36 [nonogram](/questions/tagged/nonogram) puzzle, above. Then apply some [grid-deduction-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction-deduction) (!) and discover its name!

<sub>A csv version of the nonogram (for copy-paste purposes) is provided below.</sub>

```
,,,1,,,,1,
,,,1,,,,1,
,,,1,3,5,3,1,
1,1,1,,,,,,
,,3,,,,,,
,,5,,,,,,
,,3,,,,,,
1,1,1,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,4,5,5,,,,,,,,,,,4,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,6,6,6,4,,,,,,,,,2,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,4,4,4,,1,1,1,
,,,,,,1,1,1,4,8,9,9,,,,,,4,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1
,,,,,,4,4,4,1,2,3,3,,,,,,1,4,4,4,,,,,16,16,16,,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,4
,,,,,,2,1,1,4,10,10,10,8,,,,,4,1,1,1,,,,,1,1,1,16,2,1,1,4,8,8,8,1
,,,,,,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,8,20,20,20,20,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,8
,,,,,,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,8,8,8,1,1,1,1,1,8,8,8,1
,,,,,,4,4,4,4,2,1,1,4,12,12,12,12,1,1,1,1,28,28,28,28,2,1,1,8,12,12,12,12,2,1,1,8
,,,,12,12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,15,14,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,13,12,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,12,12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2,12,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,12,6,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,3,14,6,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,3,12,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,4,2,4,12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,4,4,16,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,7,6,12,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,7,4,12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2,4,8,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2,4,14,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,5,4,9,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,3,4,8,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,20,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,20,10,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,22,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,20,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,4,2,7,4,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,6,6,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,4,24,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,4,26,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,6,24,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,4,24,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,8,16,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,2,8,18,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,12,16,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,8,16,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,4,4,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,7,6,7,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,5,4,7,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,4,4,4,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: A csv version or a penpa+ version?

Comment: Penpa link for big nonogram: https://tinyurl.com/29oywx7t (note: there is maybe a 25% chance that I have actually transcribed it all correctly)

Comment: Thanks @GarethMcCaughan - that all looks correct to me. Knew I'd forgotten something when posting!

Comment: Are you familiar with the game Squarecells? This appears to be very similar to Squarecells, assuming I'm not misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a

> Nonosweeper

Solution:

> First, solve the Nonogram to get this grid:
>  [image: Nonogram]
>  The nonogram shows numbers from 2 to 6, arranged in a 8x9 pattern. The little nonogram in the corner is an additional clue that these numbers represent the hints on a minesweeper grid. Solved, it looks like this:
>  [image: Minesweeper]
>  If we just look at the positions of the mines, we can interpret them as braille (we need to shift the middle line over one square):
>  [image: Braille]

Comment: Well done! I got the second stage, and was sure there would be at least one more, but couldn't spot it.

Comment: I also got to the second stage. I tried using binary since every row was 8 squares but it didn't work. Then unfortunately I had to leave, so I couldn't try other things

Comment: A superb first answer - well done, and welcome to Puzzling :) Detailed, all of the steps spelled out, and - above all - correct! Here's your first PSE checkmark - hopefully the first of many!

Comment: PS Love how in your second image you replicated the 'official colours' too! :)

Comment: I don't get the point of the smaller nonogram. (cc @Stiv )

Comment: @msh210 rot13(Vg'f n zvarfjrrcre obzo), intended as an additional clue to identifying the second part.

Comment: I know you have limited resolution to show the numbers, but I'm having trouble recognizing the 3 as 3 :o